# Angular 5 get URL from State: RouterStateSnapshot when open it by clicking on URL in chat, mail or same

Tags: angular, routes, navigation

I try to navigate to requested (opened) URL after requested login.
My auth-guard.service.ts is down.
For this code it works fine if I type url in browser than click enter.
But if I click (navigate) the url by clicking on it from other web page or some chat, state.url has only / . Could somebody help me to get state.url in case when I navigate to requested URl by clicking on url from some location?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, CanActivateChild, Router, ActivatedRoute,        
ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service'

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    //Get URL from State
    let url: string = state.url;
    alert("Url catched from state: " + url);
    this.checkLogin(url);

    return new Observable<boolean>(
        result => {
            result.next(true);
        }
    );
}

canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
}

checkLogin(url: string): void {
    if (this.authService._isLoggedIn) {
        return;
    }     

    this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);        
}
```